# What type (HVM, PV) of CoreOS Docker machine should I choose to run on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

My project is about to run on Docker mostly.

I have discovered today a ready to use AWS CloudFormation stacks on coreos.com (https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-ec2.html)
I'm a bit surprised with the possibility to pick PV because
my experience with AWS is that HVM machines could be resized after stop which is not possible for PV machines.

Is there a performance handicap for which I should I choose PV for CoreOS? Or should I stay with HVM for better elasticity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to resize PV instances on AWS, the only limitation is that you can't resize an instance that was launched from a PV AMI to an instance type that is HVM only. More on this topic you could read in [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)

So depending on your needs you might want to stick with particular instance type depending on your growth expectations.

Historically, PV guests had better performance than HVM guests in many cases, but because of enhancements in HVM virtualization and the availability of PV drivers for HVM AMIs, this is no longer true.

There is a good article by Amazon on virtualization types, so you would probably like to read it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html

According to my recent investigations – the common trend nowadays is to use HVM over PV. And as there is nothing beneficial in terms of performance for your case - I don't see any reason to stick with PV.

I'd also recommend to take a look to this article as well: 
[AWS in 2015: Why You Need to Switch from PV to HVM](https://www.opswat.com/blog/aws-2015-why-you-need-switch-pv-hvm)

Comment: I'd agree. Many years ago, PV tended to be better performing than HVM. But in the last year, I've actually had better luck with my HVM CoreOS instances than PV.